# How Select only specific feature from selected features of more than one layer

Tags: arcobjects

I selected features using select feature tool in a map. I want to fetch only specified features among all selected features of different layers. For example, I want to fetch only roads among all selected features(roads, river, buildings..etc). How to do it in .net?
Please help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a snippet that can get you started. Not sure what type of coding you are doing but this is C# from a 10.0 Add-in:

```
        IMxDocument mxDoc = (IMxDocument)ArcMap.Application.Document;
        IMap map = mxDoc.FocusMap;

        if (map.SelectionCount == 0) return null;

        //GET ALL SELECTED FEATURES
        IEnumFeature enumFeature = (IEnumFeature)map.FeatureSelection;

        //DEFAULT FEATURE SELECTION ONLY INCLUDES SHAPE, GET ALL FIELDS
        IEnumFeatureSetup enumFeatSetup = (IEnumFeatureSetup)enumFeature;
        enumFeatSetup.AllFields = true;

        //LOOP SELECTED FEATURES AND DO SOMETHING WITH THEM
        enumFeature.Reset();
        IFeature selectedFeature = enumFeature.Next();

        while (selectedFeature != null)
        {

            selectedFeature = enumFeature.Next();
        }
```

Using the above loop you can iterate through the selected features. Depending on your requirements you can check a value of the selectedFeature or compare the name of the layer, etc. For example, you can check if siteFeature.Class.AliasName == "My Roads Layer" or something like that. You can grab the value of a field by using siteFeature.Table.GetRow(siteFeature.OID).get_Value()

Comment: Hi Rich, thanks for your solution. It really worked. I am happy..:) By the way i am using C#